# Proving conditional expectation expression

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

Say I have a random vector $(X, Y, Z)'$, how can I prove that $E[g(X, Y)|Z=z]=\sum_{x} \sum_{y} g(x,y) p_{X,Y|Z}(x,y|Z=z)$?

I know that in general $E[g(X, Y)|Y=y]=\sum_{x}  g(x,y) p_{X|Y}(x|Y=y)$ because $g(X, Y)$ conditional on $Y = y$ is just a function of $X$, so we can let $h(X) = g(X, Y)$ (given $Y=y$). Then, by the definition of conditional expectation, we get $E[h(X) | Y=y] = \sum_{x} h(x) p_{X|Y}(x|Y=y) = \sum_{x}  g(x,y) p_{X|Y}(x|Y=y)$.

But what if the conditioning is now on $Z=z$? How can I arrive at the required expression?